# How to combine a list with a list of sublists

Tags: list-manipulation

i hope some of you can support to solve my problem, i need to work on data in the following way, where the length of each of the lists or sublists is equal. As an example i want to share the data-pattern with you:

```
list1={a,b,c};
list2={{d,e,f},{g,h,i},......} (in reality the number of sublists in list2 is about 30)
data=list2[[1]]
```

the goal is now to combine these lists in the following form
`{ {{a,d},{b,e},{c,f}}, {{a,g},...} ...}` .

---

The next step to plot it or to create a fit-formula. The values of list1 should be always plotted as the x-Data.
I created some of the most interesting datasets as follows: `

```
plottedList=Table[{list1[[k]], data[[k]]}, {k, 1, Length[data]}]
ListPlot[plottedList]
```

My Problem is that i now would need to plot all of the data-pairs and combine the data to create the lists which i can find a linear or nonlinear fit.

---

I hope you can give me some advice,
Best Chris!

Comment: To answer the second part of your question (which probably should be its own separate question altogether), it would be much more helpful if you could share a portion of the actual numerical data and specify what problems you encountered that are not solved by the approaches proposed in the answers below.

Answer (score 7):

A minor variation based on @kglr's answer.

```
list1 = {a, b, c};
list2 = {{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
MapThread[List, {list1, #}] & /@ list2
```

---

Using Transpose:

```
Transpose[{list1, #}] & /@ list2
```

---

Result:

> {{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}, {{a, g}, {b, h}, {c, i}}}

Answer (score 6):

```
list1 = {a, b, c};
list2 = {{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};

Map[Thread[{list1, #}] &] @ list2
```

> ```
> {{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}, {{a, g}, {b, h}, {c, i}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
Inner[{#2,#1}&,list2,list1,List]

(* {{{a, d}, {b, e}, {c, f}}, {{a, g}, {b, h}, {c, i}}} *)
```

**A Slot-free version**

[J. M. can't deal with it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-cant-deal-with-it)  (in a comment) gives the following neat modification:

```
Inner[ReverseApplied[List], list2, list1, List]
```

**Lists**

```
list1 = {a, b, c};
list2 = {{d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
```

Comment: Very nice. Here's a slot-free version: `Inner[ReverseApplied[List], list2, list1, List]`